# Generating PWM using Arduino Uno and Simulink (interfacing) pins 5 and 6. What's the maximum frequency?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am building a boost converter using a mosfet. The mosfet is driven by PWM generated by an Arduino Uno through Matlab Simulink. In Simulink I am giving 10 KHz pulse width 50%. Practically 10 KHz available at pins 5 and 6. Up to how much frequency can pins 5 and 6 handle?

Comment: I think the maximum frequency is 4MHz. I wouldn't use pins 5 and 6, as those use timer0, which is already used by `millis` and `delay`. You'd better of using pins 9 and 10 which use timer1.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite

Comment: Just posting a link isn't very useful. What do you mean?

Comment: in the above link it states The frequency of the PWM signal on most pins is approximately 490 Hz. On the Uno and similar boards, pins 5 and 6 have a frequency of approximately 980 Hz

Comment: The implementation of analogWrite uses 490 and 980 Hz, but that doesn't mean you can't use other speeds. You can use a smaller prescaler for the timer being used.

Comment: pin 9 and 10 can handle frequency of 10khz.?

Comment: Yes. Though you'd have to tweak some of the registers to get this exact frequency. If the frequency doesn't need to be exact you could just change the default /64 prescaler to e.g /1 to get around 30kHz.

Comment: PS the maximum PWM frequency is [actually 8MHz](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L286-L287).

Comment: highest frequency achivable using arduino while serially communicating.?

Comment: Still 8MHz.....

Comment: How much frequency do you need and how many bits of PWM resolution do you need?

Comment: 1okhz  is designed for boost converter

Answer (score 1):

See [my page about timers](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers). The maximum frequency the hardware can output is 8 MHz if you are running a 16 MHz clock.

10 kHz should be easily achievable if you tweak the hardware registers, as Gerben said.

Answer (score 0):

> Up to how much frequency can pins 5 and 6 handle?

here is a way for you to find out:

1) pin 5/6 are OC0A and OC0B -> two output compare pins tied to timer0

2) go to the datasheet and timer0 is a 8-bit timer, with a few pwm modes who top out at 0xff or OCR0A -> useless for your application.

So the theoretical but useless answer is 16Mhz/2, at 1:1 prescaler.

the more practical answer is 16Mhz / 256, at 1:1 prescaler.

with that said, some AVRs (ATtiny25/45/85 for example) can run in asynchronous modes generating incredibly high PWM with very little outside help.

if generating high speed pwm is your thing, check them out instead.